# Exibir a soma de cada linha de uma matriz gerada aleatoriamente

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho o seguinte programa que gera uma matriz aleatória conforme a quantidade de linhas e colunas desejadas. Nele também é localizado e exibido o maior valor dos elementos, e sua posição (coluna e linha).

Como faço para exibir a soma de cada linha da matriz gerada?

```
def gerar(nLins, nCols, min, max):
    from random import randint
    vals = [None] * nLins
    for i in range(nLins):
        vals[i] = [0] * nCols
        for j in range(nCols):
            vals[i][j] = randint(min, max)
    return vals



def mostrar(vals, linMin, linMax, colMin, colMax):
    for i in range(linMin, linMax):
        for j in range(colMin, colMax):
            print(vals[i][j], end=" ")
        print()
    print()
    return None


def localizaCelulaComMaiorValor(vals):
    resp = (0, 0)
    for lin in range(len(vals)):
        for col in range(len(vals[lin])):
            if vals[lin][col] > vals[resp[0]][resp[1]]:
                resp = (lin, col)
    return resp


qtd = input().split()
qtdLinhas = int(qtd[0])
qtdColunas = int(qtd[1])

valores = gerar(qtdLinhas, qtdColunas, 100, 999)
mostrar(valores, 0, qtdLinhas, 0, qtdColunas)

ondeMaior = localizaCelulaComMaiorValor(valores)
print("O maior valor é", valores[ondeMaior[0]] [ondeMaior[1]],"-> Localizado na coluna",
      ondeMaior[1],"/ linha", ondeMaior[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saudações, meu amigo ! Eu rodei seu código aqui, pra implementar o que se pede diretamente nele, e bom, eu criei a seguinte função que faz exatamente o que você está pedindo, da uma olhada nela, não é nada difícil e garanto que irás entender rápido:

```
def somaLinhas(vals, colMax):
    n = 1
    for val in vals:
        soma = 0 
        j = 0
        while j < colMax:
            soma = soma + val[j]
            j += 1
        print(f'Soma da linha {n} = {soma}')
        n += 1
```

Ao implementar essa função no seu código e a chamar, no final do código mesmo, ela retorna a seguinte saída:

> Soma da linha 1 =  3556
>   Soma da linha 2 =  2452
>   Soma da linha 3 =  2813
>   Soma da linha 4 =  2457

A função implementada funciona da seguinte forma, como a matriz gerada possui separadamente as linhas com seus valores, é só somar cada item dessas linhas, até chegar na última coluna, ao chegar nela, ele zera a coluna mas segue para a próxima linha, e assim por diante, se quiser salvar os valores dessas somas e não só exibi-los, aconselho a criar uma lista e ir dando 'append' conforme for gerando as somas, é isso, abraços !

Caso queira somar as colunas a seguinte função se faz necessária:

```
def somaColunas(vals, linMax, colMax):
    j = 0
    n = 0
    soma = 0
    while n < colMax:
        for val in vals:
            soma = soma + val[j]
        j += 1
        n += 1
        print(f'A soma da coluna {n} = {soma}')
        soma = 0
```

O funcionamento desta é fundamentalmente diferente da outra, contudo mais simples, nessa você vai somar o elemento val[j] de cada linha, ou seja, começando com o primeiro valor de todas as linhas, e quando chegar na última linha, ele recomeça, contudo o 'j' é acrescido de 1, assim ele ira pra próxima coluna, e isso sucessivamente até percorrer toda a matriz, recomendo dar uma olhada nesse código e tentar replicá-lo em outras aplicações para treinar. Espero ter ajudado !

Comment: O 'n' dentro da função é referente a numeração da linha, só pra deixar claro, pode ser nomeado de 'i' sem problemas, é só força do hábito de nomear de 'n' mesmo.

Comment: Muito obrigada cara! Funcionou aqui. Caso eu queira somar também as colunas, tentei alterar o colMax pelo linMax e não funcionou. Como sou principiante, sei que to dando mole em algo. Onde seria a alteração para que eu somasse e exibisse também cada coluna?

Comment: Opa, tem como fazer isso sim, não bastava alterar o parâmetro de entrada, mas sim a lógica de como percorrer a matriz, alterei a resposta pra responder ao seu comentário, dá uma olhada lá !

Answer (score 1):

Como a "matriz" é na verdade uma lista de listas, basta percorrê-la com um `for` simples para iterar pelas linhas (não precisa criar um `range` para isso, veja mais detalhes abaixo). E como cada linha é uma lista de números, basta usar a [função `sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) para encontrar a soma dos seus valores:

```
m = gerar(5, 4, 1, 10)
for i, linha in enumerate(m):
    print('soma da linha {} = {}'.format(i + 1, sum(linha)))
```

Também usei a [função `enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) para obter o índice da linha, juntamente com a própria linha. Ao imprimir, somei 1 ao número, já que os índices começam em zero (a primeira linha é zero, a segunda é 1, etc). A saída é (os valores variam, já que você está usando números aleatórios na geração):

```
soma da linha 1 = 23
soma da linha 2 = 25
soma da linha 3 = 13
soma da linha 4 = 19
soma da linha 5 = 17
```

---

#### Bônus

Você não precisa usar [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) e [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) para percorrer a "matriz". Em Python, listas (e qualquer objeto que seja [iterável](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13054109])) podem ser percorridas com um `for` diretamente, sem precisar usar `range` (e caso queira os índices dos elementos, basta usar `enumerate`, como já visto acima). Seus métodos poderiam ser assim:

```
def mostrar(vals):
    for linha in vals: # percorre as linhas da matriz
        for elemento in linha: # percorre os elementos da linha
            print(elemento, end=" ")
        print()
    print()

def localizaCelulaComMaiorValor(vals):
    maior = vals[0][0]
    pos = (0, 0)
    for i, linha in enumerate(vals):
        for j, elemento in enumerate(linha):
            if elemento > maior:
                maior = elemento
                pos = (i, j)
    return pos
```

O uso de valores específicos para as linhas e colunas só fariam sentido se você quisesse percorrer uma parte da matriz. Mas se quer percorrer todos os elementos, um `for` simples já resolve (e use o `enumerate` se quiser saber o respectivo índice de cada elemento - mas no caso da função `mostrar`, por exemplo, você não precisa dos índices, então faça um `for` diretamente na "matriz", que você já estará iterando pelas suas linhas - na verdade pelos seus elementos, que no caso também são listas, e por isso também podem ser percorridas por outro `for`).